# What is prefer , bucket or repartition?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 spark jobs one is pre-process and the second is the process.
Process job needs to calculate for each user in the data.
I want  to avoid shuffle like groupBy so I think about to save the result of the pre-process as bucket by user in Parquet or to re-partition by user and save the result .

What is prefer ? and why

Comment: Can you show the query?

Answer (score 3):

Choice between `partitionBy` and `bucketBy` can be reduced to determine data cardinality:

- Low cardinality -> partition
- Hight cardinality -> bucket

However neither is used for aggregations. There are used for predicate pushdown, nothing more. Therefore they won't be of much use when your goal is to *to avoid shuffle like groupBy* although it might change in the future with the new API.

Comment: thanks for you answer. If I will save the data as bucket by user so the next job that read it can work with mapPartition and I dont need grouping again . so why is not avoid shuffle?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this twice or thrice to understand this.

In my recommendation you should use repartition as partitionby has lot of shuffle. As it will create the folder in HDFS with all the partition key and further it will add data into different files which is very expensive process. Also bucketby attribute adds up the same but create files inside the folder in order of their previous partition.

Repartition on the other hand create hash table of all the data being stored in the file which is sorted by the key you mention here. And data shuffle is just to match the number of files u mention in the repartition attribute whihh is less expensive and pretty fast. Also if u want to groupby on this data that the running time will be same as of partitionby. By repartition u just reduce the run time for pre-process.